# SQL ANY query - valid syntax

Tags: sql, any

Trying to use the following 'ANY' syntax and gets an error:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Em.ename
FROM Emp Em, Dept D
WHERE Em.eid In (Select D.managerid 
                 FROM Dept D
                 GROUP BY D.managerid
                 HAVING EVERY (D.budget > 1000000) AND ANY (D.budget < 5000000)
             );
```

Error output:

```
psql:queries.sql:28: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ANY"
LINE 6:      HAVING EVERY (D.budget > 1000000) AND ANY (D.budget < 5...
                                                     ^
```

Edit: I am using Postgres and connecting using Psql.

Comment: what DB engine are you using?

Comment: I knew `ALL`, `ANY` and `SOME`. First time I hear of `EVERY`

Comment: Plus, you are not joining the two tables.

Comment: Postgres indeed. 
@gbn - On a certain table, your first SELECT returned different from the second one, which returned the desired results.

"enames of managers who manage only departments with budgets larger than $1 
million, but also manage at least one department with budget less than $5 million."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it simpler, no?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Em.ename
FROM Emp Em, Dept D
WHERE Em.eid In (Select D.managerid 
                 FROM Dept D
                 WHERE D.budget > 1000000             
                 GROUP BY D.managerid
                 HAVING MIN(D.budget) < 5000000
             );
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT Em.ename
FROM Emp Em, Dept D
WHERE Em.eid In (Select D.managerid 
                 FROM Dept D
                 GROUP BY D.managerid
                 HAVING EVERY (D.budget > 1000000) AND MIN(D.budget) < 5000000
             );
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT Em.ename
FROM Emp Em, Dept D
WHERE Em.eid In (Select D.managerid 
                 FROM Dept D
                 GROUP BY D.managerid
                 HAVING MIN (D.budget) > 1000000 AND MIN(D.budget) < 5000000
             );
```

Comment: I don't think that the first query is equivalent to what the OP asks for.

Comment: Postgres indeed. @gbn - On a certain table, your first SELECT returned different from the second one, which returned the desired results. "enames of managers who manage only departments with budgets larger than $1 million, but also manage at least one department with budget less than $5 million."

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, 2nd and 3rd look fine (3rd also needing `D.budget` never to be `NULL`).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Em.ename
FROM Emp Em                                            --- only Emp table
WHERE Em.eid In (Select D.managerid 
                 FROM Dept D
                 GROUP BY D.managerid
                 HAVING ALL (D.budget > 1000000)       --- ALL
                   AND ANY (D.budget < 5000000)
             );
```